# Incrementally transfer objects

Tags: c#, serialization, observable, deserialization

I wanted to sync an object with another object on a different computer.

The Problem: The Object is very big. It's a list with approximately 100 000 000 Entries.

I want to sync the object basically after every change, but this means i have to serialize and deserialize the entire list after every single time.

Is there a way to incrementally send the changes to the other computer?

btw. using an sql-database or something like that is not possible, i am bound to the list

Comment: How does the list change?

Comment: can you isolate the specific changes? for example, would it be possible to know when you're making changes like "update element with index 13423 to {payload}", "delete element at 234234", "insert new element at 2311 with {payload}" "append new element with {payload}" ? if so, you could send deltas based on that? to keep things simple, a full export can just be N x "append"

Comment: @MarcGravell So you say i would be better off trying to manually create deltas on every writing operation of the list?

Comment: @HerzogVolpe if you don't want to transmit the entire list, then yes: some kind of delta mechanism is the way to go

Comment: What type of entries? How large is each entry? Does order matter? Is the number of entries fixed? Will changes be done individually, or in batches? If in batches, is there any pattern to the changes? How often will updates be made? The best strategy will depend on the specifics, that are lacking from the question.